# What is required for a remote starter system in a vehicle without a transponder key?

Tags: subaru, starter, key, security

I have been looking at remote starter information, bypass kits and transponder key boxes, but my current car starts without a transponder. A fob is required to unlock the doors without the alarm going off (just the key can still unlock the doors, but the alarm will go off although this can be turned off once inside with the key and no fob in the ignition) My key is just a flat piece of metal with no chip. Do I still need a bypass module for this? Every site for finding modules by car make/model never had my specific make/model listed. It is a 2004 Subaru Outback station wagon edition.

Comment: For clarity, the transponder is the small RFID chip embedded within the plastic shroud of the actual ignition key.  It is my understanding that most vehicles have this feature from around 1997 onwards.  The transponder is read by an electromagnetic ring embedded into the ignition barrel.

Answer (score 1):

Uhm! According to this page your year model does have a transponder:
https://www.centrochiaviauto.it/tcatalogo/transponder_catalog/subaru_transponder_catalog.html

Answer (score 0):

No, from what you've said your car does't have an immobilizer, so you won't need anything special at all for a remote start.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need a way to disable the alarm, assuming your alarm has immobilizing features.
If your alarm does not immobilize, then you don't need anything special at all.